# Unity: The type is not interceptable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to resolve a dependency on the class Called from within a class Service. The registration look like this

```
private static IUnityContainer RegisterServices(this IUnityContainer container)
{
    return container
        .RegisterWithPolicy<IService, Service>(new InjectionProperty("UnityContainer", container))
        .RegisterWithPolicy<ICalled, Called>()
        ;
}
```

I use reflection to find the right implementation of ICalled (there is more than one implementation of it).

```
var type = _typeFinder.FindMyType(myObject);
var instance = (ICalled)UnityContainer.Resolve(type);
```

But when I execute the code I get this error

```
Exception is: ArgumentException - The type Called is not interceptable.
Parameter name: interceptedType
At the time of the exception, the container was:
    Resolving Namespace.Called,(none)
```

I tried using the ServiceLocator and the EnterpiseLibrary to Resolve the type, but I get the same error.
I cannot use an Activator since Called (and the other implementations) all have different interface dependencies.
Any hint?

Comment: You can use "Named registrations" to map one interface to one or more types.

Comment: @Legends make it an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Unity is dead, no more maintenance...